# Add multiple objects as value to key in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry about the title - I didn't know how else to explain it. However, I am initializing an object like this:

```
var form = {};
form.title = 'Titel';
form.fields = { type: 'radio', label: 'First name', id: 1 }
```

Then I'm adding to the object:

```
form.fields.choices = { text : "Standard", value : "Standard" , isSelected : false, price : ''};
```

That gives me the following array:

```
Array (
    [title] => Titel
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [type] => radio
            [label] => First name
            [id] => 1
            [choices] => Array
                (
                    [text] => Standard
                    [value] => Standard
                    [isSelected] => false
                    [price] => 
                )

        )

)
```

However, I would like to add multiple arrays to the choices key like this:

```
Array (
    [title] => Titel
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [type] => radio
            [label] => First name
            [id] => 1
            [choices] => Array(
                Array (
                    [text] => Standard1
                    [value] => Standard1
                    [isSelected] => false
                    [price] => ),
                Array (
                    [text] => Standard2
                    [value] => Standard2
                    [isSelected] => false
                    [price] => )

                )
            )

)
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: You switch between object and arrays in your second code block. Do you want form.fields.choices to be an array or an object?

Comment: Note: they're not associative arrays, they're just objects.

Comment: Not really sure whether I need arrays or objects. I am sending it to PHP with Ajax, where I need it to have the following structure: http://pastebin.com/T83H5S8C

Answer (score 2):

Make options an array

```
form.fields.choices = []
```

then

```
form.fields.choices[0] = { text : "Standard", value : "Standard" , isSelected : false, price : ''}

form.fields.choices[1] = { text : " Standard 2", value : "Standard" , isSelected : false, price : ''}
```

Comment: Or use `choices.push({...})` if you don't want to mess up with keys

Comment: Or in one line:

`form.fields.choices = [{ text : "Standard", value : "Standard" , isSelected : false, price : ''}, { text : " Standard 2", value : "Standard" , isSelected : false, price : ''}];`

Comment: Hmm. I think the keys that I get by doing that is messing something up. I am sending the finished array to php with ajax. In my PHP script, it needs to imitate this structure: http://pastebin.com/T83H5S8C

Comment: that's a different question but make sure your doing the JSON serialization/deserialization correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Add increment values and another array accordingly.

```
    var choices = [];

    const choice = {
       <values>
    };

    Object.keys(choice).forEach((key, index) => {
        if (data.search(key) !== -1) {
            choices.push(choice[key]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = [];

var form_object = {};
form_object.title = "Title";
form_object.fields = [];

var field_object = {};
field_object.type = "Radio";
field_object.label = "First name";
field_object.id = 1;
field_object.choices = [];

var choice_object1 = {};
choice_object1.text = "Standard";
choice_object1.value = "Standard";
choice_object1.isSelected = false;
choice_object1.price = '';

var choice_object2 = {};
choice_object2.text = "Standard 2";
choice_object2.value = "Standard 2";
choice_object2.isSelected = false;
choice_object2.price = '';

field_object.choices.push(choice_object1);
field_object.choices.push(choice_object2);

form_object.fields.push(field_object);

form.push(form_object);
```